# Entity Framework Cascade Delete Not Working Properly

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework, sqlite, cascade

I'm working on a WPF Application using EF6 with SQlite database. I have three tables in the database:

**Classes:**

```sql
CREATE TABLE "Classes" (
    "Id"    INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE,
    "Name"  TEXT,
    "SeasonId"  INTEGER,
    FOREIGN KEY("SeasonId") REFERENCES "Seasons"("Id") ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

**Seasons:**

```sql
CREATE TABLE "Seasons" (
    "Id"    INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE,
    "Name"  TEXT
);
```

**Students:**

```sql
CREATE TABLE "Students" (
    "Id"    INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE,
    "FirstName" TEXT,
    "LastName"  TEXT,
    "Number"    TEXT,
    "Points"    TEXT,
    "ClassId"   INTEGER,
    "SeasonId"  INTEGER,
    FOREIGN KEY("ClassId") REFERENCES "Classes"("Id") ON DELETE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY("SeasonId") REFERENCES "Seasons"("Id") ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

I have one to many relationships:
- A **Season** entity can have **many** classes and students.
- A **Class** entity can have **many** students with **one** Season.
- A **Student** entity has **one** Class and **one** Season.
**My Entity classes:**

**Season.vb**

```vb
Namespace Models
    Public Class Season
        Public Property Id As Integer
        Public Property Name As String
        Public Property Students As ICollection(Of Student)
        Public Property Classes As ICollection(Of [Class])
    End Class
End Namespace
```

**Class.vb**

```vb
Namespace Models
    Public Class [Class]
        Public Property Id As Integer
        Public Property SeasonId As Integer
        Public Property Name As String
        Public Property Students As ICollection(Of Student)
        Public Property Season As Season
    End Class
End Namespace
```

**Student.vb**

```vb
Namespace Models
    Public Class Student
        Public Property Id As Integer
        Public Property SeasonId As Integer
        Public Property ClassId As Integer
        Public Property FirstName As String
        Public Property LastName As String
        Public Property Number As Integer
        Public Property Points As Integer
        Public Property Season As Season
        Public Property [Class] As [Class]
    End Class
End Namespace
```

And my **DbContext class**

```vb
Namespace Data
    Public Class Context
        Inherits DbContext
        Public Overridable Property Students As DbSet(Of Student)
        Public Overridable Property Seasons As DbSet(Of Season)
        Public Overridable Property Classes As DbSet(Of [Class])

        Public Sub New()
            MyBase.New("name=DbConnString")
        End Sub
        Protected Overrides Sub OnModelCreating(modelBuilder As DbModelBuilder)

            modelBuilder.Entity(Of Student).ToTable("Students")
            modelBuilder.Entity(Of Season).ToTable("Seasons")
            modelBuilder.Entity(Of [Class]).ToTable("Classes")

            modelBuilder.Entity(Of [Class]).HasMany(Function(c) c.Students).WithRequired(Function(s) s.Class).HasForeignKey(Function(s) s.ClassId)

            modelBuilder.Entity(Of Season).HasMany(Function(s) s.Classes).WithRequired().HasForeignKey(Function(c) c.SeasonId)
            modelBuilder.Entity(Of Season).HasMany(Function(s) s.Students).WithRequired().HasForeignKey(Function(s) s.SeasonId)

            MyBase.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder)
        End Sub

    End Class
End Namespace
```

If I delete a season entity manually from the database using DB Browser for SQlite all child entites are deleted automatically.
If I add new data with code and delete it immediately, It works as expected and deletes all child entities.
But If I add data to the database manually using DB Browser or If I add the data with code, close the application, run again and then try to delete the **Season**  entity child entites are not deleted.

Here's my **Delete method**

```vb
Public Shared Function DeleteSeason(ByVal s As Season) As String
        Try
            Using db As New Context
                db.Seasons.Attach(s)
                db.Seasons.Remove(s)
                db.SaveChanges()
            End Using
            Return ""
        Catch ex As Exception
            Return ex.Message
        End Try
    End Function
```

I'm assuming it has something to do with my DbContext instance not tracking the state of the child entities or I can be completely wrong.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you enabling foreign keys after opening the database? https://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html

Comment: @Shawn I've used the SQL command `PRAGMA foreign_keys` and the returned result is 1. So I'm guessing foreign keys are enabled. And also If I use a singleton DbContext class instead of `Using End Using`code block the cascade works. But I'm trying to avoid a singleton DbContext as it is not recommended.